# Postgres view column references

Tags: postgresql, information-schema

Using the Postgres `information_schema` or system catalogs, is it possible to determine what table columns are referenced by the columns in a view?

`information_schema.view_column_usage` provides information on columns that are *used* in a view, not necessarily *selected* as a column.

`pg_class` and `pg_attribute` provide some info, but there doesn't seem to be a way to map columns from a view where an alias has been used.

Is is it possible to get the column references of the *selected* columns in a view?

Comment: There is `pg_get_viewdef()` that will give you the definition of a view: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL doesn't track which view column depends on which object. It is the view as a whole that is tracked.

But PostgreSQL tracks on which table columns (and other objects) a view depends: Each view is related to its *query rewrite rule* in `pg_rewrite`, and the query rewrite rule has a dependency on the table columns (and other objects) used in the view. These dependencies are tracked in `pg_depend`.

Putting the pieces of the puzzle together is straightforward, but takes a while. I have written [a blog](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/tracking-view-dependencies-in-postgresql/) about this recently.

Comment: I read your blog, very informative, I understand a bit more about view dependencies. But the problem remains, all dependencies of `pg_rewrite` are listed regardless of whether or not they are in the select list of the view. It seems like the only way to map view columns to their source columns is to somehow query `ev_action` in `pg_rewrite`

Comment: A view colum does not necessarily relate to a table column. Consider `CREATE VIEW xy AS SELECT count(*) FROM a JOIN b USING (c)`. Yes, you'd have to analyze `ev_action`, but that would mean to write a C function that uses a tree walker.